# How to tell Gulp to skip or ignore some files in gulp.src([...])?

Tags: css, gulp, gulp-concat

How can I tell Gulp to skip or ignore some files in `gulp.src([...])`? For instance, I **don't want to compress and concat** this file in my css/ folder - `'css/ignnore.css'`?

```
var autoprefix = require('gulp-autoprefixer'),
    concat = require('gulp-concat'),
    minifyCss = require('gulp-minify-css');

gulp.task('styles', function() {
  gulp.src([
      'css/ignnore.css', // ignore this file
      'css/*.css'
    ])
    .pipe(concat('styles.css'))
    .pipe(autoprefix('last 2 versions'))
    .pipe(minifyCss())
    .pipe(gulp.dest('local/view/style/base/css/dist/'));
});
```

Answer (score 64, accepted):

Add a `!`:

```
gulp.task('styles', function() {
  gulp.src([
      '!css/ignnore.css', // <== !
      'css/*.css'
    ])
    .pipe(concat('styles.css'))
    .pipe(autoprefix('last 2 versions'))
    .pipe(minifyCss())
    .pipe(gulp.dest('local/view/style/base/css/dist/'));
});
```

Comment: I do believe that the order matters, and the exclusion must be placed after the inclusion (so it have what to exclude).

Comment: @GustavoVargas Not according to [this comment](https://github.com/gulpjs/gulp/issues/837#issuecomment-68069722) on GitHub. Haven't done much research into it myself though.

Comment: FWIW I tried both orderings and got the same, correct, effect.

Answer (score 9):

Try this:

```
gulp.src(['css/**/!(ignore.css)*.css'])
```

Comment: I'm trying to do this with a file ending and it seems to not be working, no idea why! I have `'/**/!(.spec.js)*.js'` Any idea what's wrong with it? Trying everything @qwertymk

Comment: Thank you.
This seems to be working for me `var tsFiles = '!(node_modules)/**/*.ts';`

Comment: This is a very simple way to exclude files/file types.  Bravo!  My use case was to prevent `.html` files from being copied over in a lib scripts folder, and changing my gulp config src definition for 'lib' to: `lib: './src/assets/scripts/lib/**/!(*.html)*'` did the trick!

Comment: I had to remove the extension. This worked for me to ignore the app.js file but include alle other js files: assets/js/custom/!(app)*.js